# How to avoid to lose data encrypted because it was encrypted by no longer supported software?

Tags: encryption, software

How can I avoid losing data that is encrypted using methods that may become obsolete? I have valuable family records I wish to secure, so I plan to encrypt them before putting them in long-term storage. But how can I ensure that the encryption is future-proof, and that I *will* be able to access the data an arbitrary amount of time in the future?

Comment: The same issue occurs with hardware. How will you read these floppies ? Or Zip disks ? Jaz disks anyone ? Even CDROM readers are becoming rarer... The only path to redemption is _regular maintenance_: check your backups, transfer to new formats and mediums when necessary.

Comment: Use open sources softwares! (And store sources too! ;)

Comment: You need to store the entire OS, what if the libraries used become deprecated and the software can't compile anymore?

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with encrypted data, you must be careful to pay attention to the systems and software that will be necessary to decrypt it.  If at any point it becomes foreseeable that the systems or software necessary to decrypt your data will no longer be available, you then must consider alternative methods of encrypting/decrypting the data.

When an alternative encryption/decryption method is available, and deemed necessary, use your current methods to decrypt the data and then immediately re-encrypt it with the new method.

Of course, it should go without saying that you should always keep good backups of your data - in fact, the backups might be the best option for testing your new encryption/decryption method before performing it on your live data.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Iszi said, sticking with encryption products that have known algorithms can be helpful in future proofing since you can always implement a custom solution in the future if necessary as long as the algorithm needed to decode the information is also known.

The best bet is still to make sure to decrypt and re-encrypt before a particular system reaches end of life though, unless you need to encrypt for archival storage, in which case, stick to standard algorithms that can be reproduced later.

Answer (score 2):

There are some policies you can implement to help avoid being locked out of your data due to software obsolescence.

- Avoid obscure or proprietary software.  Open source is preferable.
- Keep the source code and installation binaries of your encryption/decryption utilities, in an unencrypted backup.
- Also ensure any in-house utilities or scripts necessary for accessing your data are backed up in the clear.
- Make sure all encryption/decryption keys (and their backups) are stored in a secure location.

If the security of your backup is compromised, you could re-encrypt all of your backup data or just put the old backup data in a new encrypted container.  The latter method may save a lot of time upgrading, but will add greater overhead when you need to access your backups later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest that this is a set of data where encryption is probably not the best option.

Get a securely lockable box, secure the keys and put it in a safety deposit box at your bank.

For family records, you probably want people to be able to get at them when you're not around, and you probably want to keep them a long time. Over an "arbitrary amount of time" you're also likely to forget about backing up keys, or about how you set up the encryption, or the software you need to carry across if you ever get a new PC.

Comment: I disagree here on two grounds.  First, protection of this data is very important as it will likely contain PII and other sensitive information for several generations of one's family - at least two of which are likely to be currently living.  Second, securely storing a "failsafe" copy of your encryption software and keys in a place other family members can get to is *just* as easy as storing the records themselves in a safety deposit as you suggest.

Comment: Not sure I follow why this is getting downvoted - the most secure and maintainable software is often no software at all, and one of the big issues in our industry is applying technical and software solutions to areas where technical and software solutions just aren't a good fit.

Comment: @Iszi You're making a bold prediction that generation 2 or 3 is going to be running an OS that can run the software you're storing as a failsafe (or have the technical chops to boot your VM).

Comment: For that contingency, you could store an entire pre-loaded laptop as your failsafe.  Or, you could leave instructions for them to use your own computer.  In any case, there are few solutions that offer better protection of data while at the same time enabling ease of authorized access as encryption.

Comment: I don't know of any laptops that will have a battery that lasts > 30 years and still have batteries available to buy at that time. And you're assuming that computer will still be maintained and up to date. Adding technology to this problem adds a number of things that can go wrong, whereas keys and padlocks are pretty stable.

Comment: The battery doesn't have to last that long - leave a power cable with it.  Any computer used as a failsafe doesn't necessarily need to be maintained and up to date - it just needs a functioning OS and hardware, appropriate peripherals for reading the media, a working copy of the decryption software, and a good set of decryption keys.  If I'd encrypted the data in the '80s, I could leave behind a 386 running MS-DOS pre-loaded with the appropriate software and keys - and it would be just fine 100 years later unless the data is re-encrypted with a different storage format, software, or keys.

Comment: Sorry, by 'that computer' I meant the one you referred to as 'your own computer'. Computers age - capacitors don't last, things get mouldy, things corrode. You also start assuming some skill on the end user's part that may not be relevant 30 years from now (how many people nowadays can't use a command line?). Why not bypass the problem entirely, unencrypt it and lock it up with a key you pass down through the ages? Very little requires the sort of security you're suggesting.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7443/discussion-between-bob-watson-and-iszi)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use an IT solution for a non-IT problem. Could your great aunty Mary use those 'valuable family records' if you gave them to her tomorrow, if not, then why do you expect them to be useful to her or anyone else in thirty years or more.

Forget crypto and IT solutions, this is a simple document handling situation. Paper document. Print them out and put them in a 'trusted' location such as a solicitors office or a bank box with instructions on how they are to be disposed of in the future.

Comment: Paper is not a long-term solution. Think stone/clay tablets.

Comment: The very first paper books still exist. The same can not be said of any computer medium and 30 years is not long term to anyone outside the closed IT world.

Comment: Paul - no they don't. Most paper/papyrus writings from ancient history are lost forever. The fact we have any is a small miracle.